# How to create a confirm dialog with office-js and react?

Tags: reactjs, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I'd like to write a simple confirm modal for my office excel addin written in React.

This doesn't work because window.confirm has been forbidden by officejs ([cf this explanation](https://theofficecontext.com/2015/08/18/office-add-ins-apps-for-office-and-window-alert/)).

```
onClick={() => { if (window.confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this item?')) { this.handleClick(); } }}>
```

According to [officeJS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins), I could use the dialog api but those dialogs are not modals, therefore don't match my usecase : I want the user to confirm the action before going further.

Is there another way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a modal Fabric React dialog component. From what you say about your use case, it might be what you are looking for. The reference for it is here:  [Dialog component in Fabric React](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/dialog).

Comment: Thanks, this solution is probably the easiest for us since we planned to use office-ui-fabric.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) which what I have used. Make sure you add the `url` to your AppDomain in `xml` manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Dialog API you can piggy-back of the existing react render by creating a separate HTML page (`dialog.html`) with a div with the same ID you're using to render react onto for the taskpane (e.g. `container`):

`dialog.html`

```html
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license. -->
<!-- See LICENSE in the project root for license information -->

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-framework="typescript">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Then in your main `App,tsx` file, you can have a conditional checking for that URL query variable `dialogID` and if present then render the dialog, otherwise, render the main taskpane:

```js
export function App() {
    // requires react-router-dom
    const urlQueryParameters = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

    return (
        <>

            {/* I'm a dialog window */ urlQueryParameters.get("dialogID") != null && <React.Fragment>
                <DialogWindow dialogID={urlQueryParameters.get("dialogID")}/>
            </React.Fragment>}

            {/* I'm NOT a dialog window (I'm the main taskpane ui) */ urlQueryParameters.get("dialogID") == null &&
                <React.Fragment>
                    ...
```

Then you can create dialog prompts with (passing a URL query variable signifying it's a dialog):

```js
    ...
<button onClick={() => {
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync("https://host:3000/dialog.html?dialogID=" + dialogID, {promptBeforeOpen: false, displayInIframe: true, width: 30, height: 60});
}}>Create a dialog window</button>
    ...
```